# Is it possible to add main method in c# class and run it like in Java?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Basically i know when in Java I add main method then I can run it independently on my project. But I cannot figure out how to do it in Visual Studio :(.

Comment: [Create a new console application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and you're done(Visual studio will add Main for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, each class will generate a .class file before it is compiled into a JAR or whatever binary format used to deploy it. This allows the Java executable to run a single class when it contains a main method. Unfortunately, the smallest binary format of a runnable C# application is a .exe file. A single executable project will output only one .exe file, this means each project may only have a single `Main` method.

What you can do is create a `Main` method in your class and rename the original `Main` method to `Main2` or something like that, then run your project to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define a method that is called Main in C# too.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx):

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application.
>   There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point.

```
public class Program
{
    private void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This code will run on your program's startup
    }
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that main must be public static